# Get the value of a hidden field in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a simple JQuery code where I'm trying to get the value of an ASP:HiddenField and display it, but it does not show anything.

The hidden field is in the form, not inside any table or div.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnID" runat="server" />
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnload").click(function () {
        alert($("#hdnID").text());
    });
});
```

I am setting the value of hidden field on page load and then when I click the button I want to display the value using alert. It shows an empty alert box every time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: should it be `$("#hdnID").val()`?

Comment: use $(selector).val();

Comment: What does `<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnID" runat="server" />` actually get rendered to the browser as?

Comment: Open the view source of the page and check if hidden field id is hdnID or something else. Reason is if hidden field is inside any child page or any master page is being used then id of the server controls gets changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead `alert($("#hdnID").val());`

Comment: Well, I feel so stupid now. I was trying to do this with a label first, and when I changed to the hidden field I didn't think of changing text to val. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

**If anyone tries the above and it is still not working:**

If your hidden is nested in other controls, ASP.NET will change the name of the control, so better to select for "name ends with" selector `id$`

eg:
`alert($('[id$="hdnID"]').val());`

Alternatively have ASP.NET populate the name of the control with:

`alert($('#<%= hdnID.ClientID%>').val());`

Either will insure reference to your hidden field if it is nested.

Comment: Best one. works for all. Thank you mike.